# Is it possible to use cross database queries in both Azure and SQL?

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database, polybase

I am working on a project designed to run on azure platform using Azure database and Locally using local sql server. We have stored procedure that contain cross database calls. However It doesn't works on Azure server.I need cross database queries that capable of working in both azure and local sql server.

We an use Elastic Query which allows us to query across Azure SQL Databases

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-overview/

We can setup external data source in azure server Using following code. In this case we can execute cross database calls likes joining tables in a single database.

```
 CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'yourPassword';  

 CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL yourServeradminlogin  
 WITH IDENTITY = 'yourServeradminlogin',  
 SECRET = 'yourPassword';  

 CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RefmyDemoDB2  
 WITH  
 (  
    TYPE=RDBMS,  
    LOCATION='testdbdemoserver.database.windows.net',  
    DATABASE_NAME='myDemoDB2',  
    CREDENTIAL= yourServeradminlogin  
 );  

 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[Department](  
    [DeptId] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL  
 )  
 WITH  
 (  
    DATA_SOURCE = RefmyDemoDB2  
 );
```

It doesn't seem possible to use above method on our local SQL server without adding a third party database engine.
Install something called PolyBase to do cross database query in local sql server version 2017 and above.It only supported with external data source of type such as HADOOP rather than referencing another database(or any data storage) within the sql server.

We can accomplish that using following code

```
  CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='MyP@ssword123secretword';

  CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL mycredential  
  WITH IDENTITY = 'credential', Secret = 'secretkey' 

  CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE mycustomers
  WITH (
    TYPE = HADOOP,
    LOCATION =  'wasbs://azurestorage.blob.core.windows.net/',
    CREDENTIAL = mycredential
  );

  CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT csvformat 
  WITH ( 
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT, 
    FORMAT_OPTIONS ( 
      FIELD_TERMINATOR = ','
    ) 
  );

  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TableName
  ( 
    [did] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [Dname] [varchar] (50) NULL 
  ) 
  WITH 
  ( 
     LOCATION = '/', 
     DATA_SOURCE = mycustomers, 
     FILE_FORMAT = csvformat
  )
```

Using HADOOP and polybase we can create an external data source in local sql server. But it create external data source of that external data storage. That is External data table located in that external storage.Exactly, my requirement is create an external data source of database within the sql server. So that i can use same corss data base query in both azure and local sql server

Is there any solution to solve this. or any solution to run cross database queries in both azure and local sql server?

Comment: There are bags of documents about this already published, here is just one - https://sqldusty.com/2017/05/30/setting-up-cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-database/

Comment: @jimmy8ball , Thanks for your response. The given link explains setting up of Cross Database Queries in Azure SQL Database. Actually I need to execute those queries in Local sql server. In fact Those type such as RDBMS are doesn't works on local sql server.  I already tried to build up that using following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-sql-server?view=sqlallproducts-allversions  .

Answer (score 3):

You should not assume that using external tables in SQL Azure is remotely similar to doing cross-database queries in SQL Server.  They are not the same thing and they have very different performance profiles.  External tables is closer to linked servers than cross-database queries in SQL Server.

In SQL Server, cross-database queries are:
 - running in the same SQL instance
 - run the same basic execution code path to read data vs. single-database SQL Azure
 - you have some slightly different transactional semantics vs. single-database operaitons in SQL Server, but the experience is generally similar from your perspective.

In SQL Azure singletons ("traditional") SQL Azure, you generally do not have the databases on the same physical machines.  So, you have to cross-server queries (which are exposed using a linked-server like mechanism called external tables which support sharding/fan-out scenarios mostly).  Trying to use this feature to simulate cross-database queries may functionally work, but it is not really a great plan due to the performance differences.  There are also no real transactional guarantees in this path at all (no DTC).

SQL Azure Managed Instance *does* support cross-database queries within a single SQL Server instance internally.  So, this would be the path that would be most similar for you to use if you really want to use cross-database queries.  If you want to use SQL Azure single databases, you generally would not want to do cross-db queries at all for a legacy workload and you would want to rewrite to avoid the dependency.  (Otherwise it will just be an ongoing headache due to the performance differences)

Comment: I need little more clarification. Offcourse,  Cross database query Azure Sql server is differ from traditional Sql server. In traditional Sql server we can use linked server concept or call like "[DatabaseName].[TableName]" . In azure sql server it doesn't support. Elastic Query is an Alternative way to accomplish this. Can't use Elastic query in traditional sql server to link two database within the server.  But My aim is how to make a query that joins two tables in two database, and it  must be able to use in both azure and traditional Sql server environment.

Comment: There is no single way to do this today, unfortunately, unless you use SQL Azure Managed Instance.  Then you can just do normal 3-part name queries like in SQL Server.  Elastic Query is really about scale-out query in SQL Azure (although you can squint at it and it can maybe look like a point-to-point database solution, it is not the same as cross-db query).  If you need to write code that works in both, then I suggest you #ifdef to have 2 paths as there is no T-SQL surface area to do what you are requesting.

Comment: Finally I got the solution !. There is no single way to do this. But using 'SYNONYM' in traditional sql server and using Elastic query(External table concept) in azure sql solve that problem. So that now I can use a query to link 2 tables in 2 database in both azure and traditional sql. There is no need to make changes in query depending on server. But one issue remaining. How to access Function of another db in azure sql server?. Locally 'SYNONYM' allows to access functions in another DB. (azure sql server doesn't support SYNONYM)